# Optimizing mongo query for better response

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to optimize mongodb query for better response

```
db.myReports.find({
"CheckInDate": {
    "$gte" : ISODate("2015-01-12T00:00:00Z"),
    "$lte" : ISODate("2015-03-31T00:00:00Z")
},
"SubscriberPropertyId":  NumberLong(47984),
"ChannelId": {
    "$in": [701, 8275]
},
"PropertyId": {
    "$in": [47984, 3159, 5148, 61436, 66251, 70108]
},
"LengthOfStay": 1
},     {
    "CheckInDate": 1,
   "SubscriberPropertyId": 1,
    "ChannelId": 1,
    "PropertyId": 1
});
```

Currently it is taking around 3 minutes just to find data from 3 million records.

One Document from collection

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("54dba46c320caf5a08473074"),
    "OptimisationId" : NumberLong(1),
    "ScheduleLogId" : NumberLong(3),
      "ReportId" : NumberLong(4113235),
   "SubscriberPropertyId" : NumberLong(10038),
   "PropertyId" : NumberLong(18166),
   "ChannelId" : 701,
  "CheckInDate" : ISODate("2014-09-30T18:30:00Z"),
  "LengthOfStay" : 1,
 "OccupancyIndex" : 1.0,
 "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2014-09-11T06:31:08Z"),
  "ModifiedDate" : ISODate("2014-09-11T06:31:08Z"),

 }
```

INDEX created is:

```
db.myReports.getIndexes();
[
        {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "db.myReports"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "CheckInDate" : 1,
                    "SubscriberPropertyId" : 1,
                    "ReportId" : 1,
                    "ChannelId" : 1,
                    "PropertyId" : 1
            },
            "name" :      
 "CheckInDate_1_SubscriberPropertyId_1_ReportId_1_Channe

 lId_1_PropertyId_1",
            "ns" : "db.myReports"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "CheckInDate" : 1
            },
            "name" : "CheckInDate_1",
            "ns" : "db.myReports"
    }
]
```

I have created index on possible entities

Comment: You wanna share what the documents look like, and what index you got so far?

Comment: It would be great to know how your indexes are set up

Comment: also, what is lakhs?

Comment: Technically 3 million. as a lakh is apparently 100,000 so 30 times 100,000 is 3 million. you learn something new every day. :)

Comment: I noticed your CheckInDate_1_SubscriberPropertyId_1_ReportId_1_Channe compound index has reportId, but your query doesn't. create a new compound index without reportId... that might change your query time.

Comment: Use query.explain() to check which index is being used in the query.

Comment: I already did that and correct index is used.Below is result of explain()     {
                   "cursor" : "BtreeCursor  CheckInDate_1_SubscriberPropertyId_1_ChannelId__PropertyId_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 237941,
        "nscannedObjects" : 667155,
        "nscanned" : 667324,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 667844,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 668013,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 13431,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 190741,
        "indexBounds" : {}
  
}

Answer (score 1):

Put equality queries first, then range queries:

```
db.myReports.find({
  "SubscriberPropertyId":  NumberLong(47984),
  "ChannelId": {
    "$in": [701, 8275]
  },
  "PropertyId": {
    "$in": [47984, 3159, 5148, 61436, 66251, 70108]
  },
  "CheckInDate": {
    "$gte" : ISODate("2015-01-12T00:00:00Z"),
    "$lte" : ISODate("2015-03-31T00:00:00Z")
  },
  "LengthOfStay": 1 // low selectivity, move to the end
}, {
  "CheckInDate": 1,
  "SubscriberPropertyId": 1,
  "ChannelId": 1,
  "PropertyId": 1
});
```

Make sure the index fits, i.e make the index `SubscriberPropertyId`, `ChannelId`, `PropertyId`, `CheckInDate`. `LengthOfStay` probably has too low selectivity to make sense in an index, depends on your data.

That should reduce the `nscanned` significantly, but getting 300k results will take its time (actually reading them, I mean)

Comment: both (My query and query modified by you) are giving same result. The no of nscanned elements are same, time taken is also same. Same query if I do in sql server return result in few seconds. We consider mongodb much faster than relational dbs for big data?

Comment: NoSQL isn't about speed, but scalability, and *it's not the tools* that make the difference but the paradigms your code is based on (remember facebook runs on mysql) - your approach is quite read-heavy and there's a ton of indexes, that's generally what rdbms's are good at. You'll have to reason about the selectivity of the indexes and understand the access patterns or choose a more write-heavy data structure. Also, 300k rows is hardly 'big data'... all in all, that's maybe 400M of data - I can fit 40x the amount of that in my off-the-shelf laptop's RAM...

Comment: Can you suggest any solution to current query?